# I have two questions related to getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, getchar, putchar

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
char c;
c=getchar();
putchar(c);

c=getchar();
putchar(c);

c=getchar(); 
putchar(c);

c=getchar();
putchar(c);

c=getchar();
putchar(c);

}
```

My 1st question is that whenever we use **getchar()** its create a buffer somewhere in memory and when we press enter **getchar()** starts reading content from buffer and **getchar()** read only one character at time. So in this above program when 1st **getchar()** will execute it creates a buffer in memory and whole line content will store in the buffer suppose I write "vik" when I hit enter **getchar()** starts reading content from buffer and then 'v' will assign to variable c and then only 'v' will flush from the buffer because **getchar()** reads only single character at a time. Then in next statement **putchar(c)** prints 'v' on screen. So now "ik" are left in buffer when 2nd **getchar()** statement execute it will not ask again to user to writing something because unless and until buffer will not flush totally its will not ask again to user to write something rather its read content from buffer. so here "ik" are remain in butter so in 2nd **getchar()** statement read 'i' from the buffer and then again 'i' will flush from buffer and **putchar(c)** prints 'i'. Now 'k' is left in buffer when 3rd **getchar()** execute it read 'k' from buffer and assing to c then 'k' also flush from buffer.Now at this point buffer is totally flushed,there is no content is in buffer when 4th **getchar()** will execute its ask to user to write something because there is no content is in buffer so lets suppose I write "as" and hits enter.
***Now my main question is that when I give two content "as" and there two getchar() and putchar(c) are left to execute so why only 'a' will print on screen why not 's' also ?***

And,
My second question is that, if we say that when we use **getchar()** its create a buffer in memory 
so if we use **fflush(stdin)** its have to flush the buffer. So according to this in above program when I write **fflush(stdin)** after the 1st **putchar(c)** instead of flushing buffer its executes and print same output as above program why ?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: You should add complete punctuations! (Yelling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> .Now at this point buffer is totally flushed,there is no content is in buffer when 4th getchar() will execute its ask to user to write something because there is no content is in buffer so lets suppose I write "as" and hits enter. Now my main question is that when I give two content "as" and there two getchar() and putchar(c) are left to execute so why only 'a' will print on screen why not 's' also ?

No. There is `\n` in the buffer. And that's why you are getting only `a` on inputting `as`.

> And, My second question is that, if we say that when we use getchar() its create a buffer in memory so if we use fflush(stdin) its have to flush the buffer. So according to this in above program when I write fflush(stdin) after the 1st putchar(c) instead of flushing buffer its executes and print same output as above program why ?

`fflush(stdin)` will invoke undefined behavior (by the ANSI C standard). You will get anything. You are unlucky that it prints the same output.

Comment: Not necessarily MS-DOS though, Linux also supports it: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush

Comment: **Description** part: *For input streams, `fflush()` discards any buffered data that has been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application.*

Comment: @YuHao; Interesting! Never knew that.

Answer (score 2):

1. Because the new line after `vik` is still in buffer. So the fourth `getchar()`will process the new line.
2. `fflush(stdin)` is not standard C, so undefined behavior, but some compiler supports it as an extension.

Note that you should declare `int c` otherwise you won't handle `EOF` properly. And you should check for `EOF` as well. The prototype of `getchar()` is :

```
int getchar(void);
```